# Scrapy xpath not working (maybe something with parbase?)

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

This is the [URL](http://www.nielsen.com/us/en/insights/journal-of-measurement/volume-1-issue-2/nott-alone-is-ott-making-it-cool-again-to-watch-tv-together.html) I was trying it out on. I was trying to get the body content of the article; "Co-viewing in television...". I've tried the following expressions:

```
[In 1]:response.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'text parbase')]//text()").extract()
[Out 1]:[]

[In 2]:response.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'text')]//text()").extract()
[Out 2]: [u'\n',
 u'\n',
 u'\n\n',
 u'\n    $CQ(function() {\n        CQ_Analytics.SegmentMgr.loadSegments("/etc/segmentation");\n         CQ_Analytics.ClientContextUtils.init("","/content/corporate/us/en/insights/journal-of-measurement/volume-1-issue-2/nott-alone-is-ott-making-it-cool-again-to-watch-tv-together");\n\n        \n    });\n',
 u'\n']

[In 3]:response.xpath("//p//text()").extract()
[Out 3]:[u'X']
```

And none of them seem to contain what I want it to get. Am I doing something wrong here? If this has already been answered, I'm sorry, I've tried my best to find an answer, but haven't managed to find anything just yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What's their content? and what do you expected to be their content?

Comment: @VMRuiz All the text stored inside all of the p elements in div[@class="text parbase toptext"]

Comment: As far as I can see your code is right. There seems to be some error on the HTML code that make the scrapy parse unable to load the section that you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some kind of problem on the HTML output of the website and the Scrapy parser is unable to render that section. You could extract the content using regular expresions to get a fix on that:

```
import re
from scrapy import Selector

section = re.match(r'.*(<div.*?parbase toptext.*?)</div>', response.body, re.DOTALL).group(1)
Selector(text=section).xpath('//text()').extract()
```

Comment: This seems to work well; and it's also easily extendable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see that page contains the following line:

```
<li><script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" asyncdefer=[NULL][NULL]
```

where `[NULL]` stands for a null byte.

This seems to throw off the parser. If I construct a selector using the response body with null bytes removed then it works.

Comment: In cases like this, I wish stackoverflow allowed accepting multiple answers. Both of the answers here are working well; I selected the other one since he answered a bit earlier than you. Sorry, and thanks!